# How can I apply multiple conditional formats to a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am writing a program for my job, that will read an excel file, sort by distributor, and then format each one and write them to their own excel file.

Usually done manually, this takes a few days having to copy and paste, format, and then save each file for each distributor. I have manage to get it to write all of them to their own excel file, only I am having trouble with the formatting.

I wanted all Credit Memos to be formatted with a red font, however when I apply this format, it overrides the number formatting I have in money and percent columns.

Additionally, I am having trouble adding a total to the bottom of 2 specific columns. I only need totals in 2 of the columns and the rest of the columns for that row should be empty.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried formatting the red text before the number formatting, but then when the number formatting is applied, it reverts back to a black font.

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_name = 'Report - May 2019'

data = pd.read_excel(r'path.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Store each unique distributor in a list
distributors = df['Distributor'].unique().tolist()

for d in distributors:
    path = r"path.xlsx"
    is_dist = df['Distributor'] == d
    dist = df[is_dist]
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    dist.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, header=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    # Add header format
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'fg_color': '#3FB6FF',
        'border': 1
    })

    # Set header and column width and format header
    for col_num, value in enumerate(dist.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

        column_len = dist[value].astype(str).str.len().max()
        column_len = max(column_len, len(value))

        worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, column_len)
```

> ### This is the issue
>
> ```
>    # Set Credit Memo to Red Font
>     cm_red_font = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'red'})
>     num_rows = len(dist.index)
>     for row in range(num_rows):
>         if dist.iloc[row, 14] < 0:
>             worksheet.set_row(row + 1, 15, cm_red_font)
>
>     # Add a total to 'Total Product Invoiced Amount' Column
>     #sales_sum = dist['Total Product Invoiced Amount'].sum()
>     #dist.append(pd.DataFrame)
>     #print(str(d), dist['Total Product Invoiced Amount'].iloc[len(dist.index)])
> ```

```
    # Format money columns
    money_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#0.00'})
    worksheet.set_column('L:M', 12, money_format)
    worksheet.set_column('O:O', 12, money_format)

    # Format percent column
    percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
    worksheet.set_column('N:N', 12, percent_format)

    # Format date columns
    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 12, date_format)
    worksheet.set_column('F:F', 12, date_format)

    writer.save()
```

The expected result would be multiple excel files, formatted correctly based off of conditional formatting.